# php7 ubuntu 16 upgrade php files break at "->" in php files

Tags: php-7, ubuntu-16.04

Following an upgrade of Ubuntu 14 to 16 LTS, php has been automatically updated to version 7. Running my index.php file now breaks at the first "->" and the php code is printed in my browser from that point...

i.e.

```
$obj->print(); // in php file
```

Output is...

```
print();
```

in the web-browser.

There are no errors being output in the configured or any other error file.

Answer (score 0):

Finally just reinstalled php7.0 and php5.6 from the command line along with all the required packages.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/756879/cant-install-php5-on-ubuntu-16-04